# When I try running on iOS, Delphi says I'm missing a file

Tags: ios, delphi, installation, delphi-10.1-berlin

I've been compiling and running Delphi in a VM inside a Mac. I just got a separate PC (Win10), installed Delphi, and would like to compile and run Mac and OS X apps from the new install. So here's what I did:

1. Everything on the Mac was already setup and working properly. I'll spare the details, but this is not where my issues are coming from.
2. I created a connection profile on my development machine, which succeeded--the test connection worked properly.
3. I added SDK's for Mac OSX and iOS-64 bit, following the [steps outlined on the Embarcadero docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Set_Up_Your_Development_Environment_on_Windows_PC_(iOS)). The SDK version added is iPhoneOS 11.2.
4. At this point I had no troubles compiling and running an app on Mac OSX.

When I tried it for iOS, however, I get an error `E2597`

> ld: file not found:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/FileProvider for
>   architecture arm64

I don't see a FileProvider.framework folder inside the Frameworks folder.

Comment: Please refer to: https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=900775&tstart=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried Dave's suggestion above; it got me part way there. I received an error message about missing `[long path to]/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks`. So I simply created a new folder at the designated location called "PrivateFrameworks" and tried again. ... Success!

Answer (score 1):

In case if can't find some framewwork error - add framework path in Edit SDK.

I'm using Delphi Berlin + iOS SDK 11.2 - so to fix this error - 
Tools -> Options -> SDK Manager -> Scroll down remote paths listview ->Go Frameworks section -> Select one of framework item (e.g: select /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit) -> Close it > click Add the new path item.

Enter Path: $(SDKROOT)/System/Library/Frameworks

Framework name: FileProvider

OK

Click Update cache button. 
Now it works on Berlin + iOS 11+ SDK. Checked on real iPhone with 11.2.